# SSH Brute Force Protection

Tags: security, ssh, brute-force

I currently have my raspberry pi port forwarded for SSH connection, so i can access it at work.

Whilst looking at 'journalctl -xe' i have seen tons of failed SSH login requests.

I have changed my raspberry pi to key logins rather than password based. Is there anything else i can do to stop this guy from trying to break in? Or better security to stop him accessing it?

```
Dec 20 19:46:36 raspberrypi sshd[1929]: Received disconnect from 106.250.183.218 port 20371:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Dec 20 19:46:36 raspberrypi sshd[1929]: Disconnected from 106.250.183.218 port 20371 [preauth]
Dec 20 19:47:58 raspberrypi sshd[1931]: Received disconnect from 221.194.47.245 port 37247:11:  [preauth]
Dec 20 19:47:58 raspberrypi sshd[1931]: Disconnected from 221.194.47.245 port 37247 [preauth]
Dec 20 19:48:50 raspberrypi sshd[1934]: Did not receive identification string from 23.254.161.114 port 51435
Dec 20 19:50:15 raspberrypi sshd[1935]: Did not receive identification string from 195.154.60.109 port 64642
Dec 20 19:50:15 raspberrypi sshd[1936]: Invalid user user from 195.154.60.109 port 64943
Dec 20 19:50:15 raspberrypi sshd[1936]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user [preauth]
Dec 20 19:50:15 raspberrypi sshd[1936]: error: Received disconnect from 195.154.60.109 port 64943:3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
Dec 20 19:50:15 raspberrypi sshd[1936]: Disconnected from 195.154.60.109 port 64943 [preauth]
Dec 20 20:02:05 raspberrypi sshd[1997]: Did not receive identification string from 195.154.60.109 port 51264
Dec 20 20:02:06 raspberrypi sshd[1998]: Invalid user user from 195.154.60.109 port 51418
Dec 20 20:02:06 raspberrypi sshd[1998]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user [preauth]
Dec 20 20:02:06 raspberrypi sshd[1998]: error: Received disconnect from 195.154.60.109 port 51418:3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
Dec 20 20:02:06 raspberrypi sshd[1998]: Disconnected from 195.154.60.109 port 51418 [preauth]
Dec 20 20:02:31 raspberrypi sshd[2002]: Did not receive identification string from 91.227.47.234 port 53975
Dec 20 20:02:32 raspberrypi sshd[2003]: Invalid user user from 91.227.47.234 port 53982
Dec 20 20:02:32 raspberrypi sshd[2003]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user [preauth]
Dec 20 20:02:32 raspberrypi sshd[2003]: Received disconnect from 91.227.47.234 port 53982:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Dec 20 20:02:32 raspberrypi sshd[2003]: Disconnected from 91.227.47.234 port 53982 [preauth]
Dec 20 20:03:05 raspberrypi sshd[2023]: Did not receive identification string from 103.79.142.58 port 50841
Dec 20 20:03:08 raspberrypi sshd[2024]: Invalid user user from 103.79.142.58 port 52943
Dec 20 20:03:08 raspberrypi sshd[2024]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user [preauth]
Dec 20 20:03:08 raspberrypi sshd[2024]: error: Received disconnect from 103.79.142.58 port 52943:3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
```

Comment: If you have disabled password logins then these brute force attempts are never going to be successful.  There are techniques for [rate limiting ssh connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/298954/how-can-i-rate-limit-ssh-connections-with-iptables), but I have found in practice these can be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also limit the number of attemps with fail2ban.

The default config is fine for ssh server.

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fail2ban`

Answer (score 1):

If you're not looking to disable password access to all accounts, disabling the root login via your sshd_config file (as mentioned by @ramrunner) would definitely cut down on the vast majority of SSH brute force attempts. Nevertheless, this can still leave your other login accounts vulnerable.

One way to mitigate this would be to configure iptables to only allow external SSH attempts from certain IP addresses or IP blocks. If your external work IP address does not change, you could configure iptables to block all external SSH attempts except from your work IP.

Answer (score 1):

SSH brute force attacks can suck the resources from low powered servers with a minimal amount of processors (CPU) and memory (RAM). This could be the case with your raspberry pi.

We developed a solution named [am-deny-hosts](https://github.com/Astromine/am-deny-hosts) that helps to block these attacks. It downloads IP address black lists of known SSH attackers and adds them to the `/etc/hosts.deny` file.

It is released as an open source project on [GitHub](https://github.com/Astromine/am-deny-hosts). You get a set of shell scripts that protects your raspberry PI without taking up a lot of time, CPU, or memory. Whats more we made it very simple to install.

Answer (score 0):

This question might be better migrated to serverfault or security.stackexchange.

As @larsks said, these automated attacks are in vain if you have disabled password logins. Make sure you also have

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

in your sshd_config .If you don't want to limit it yourself from iptables as per @larsks link you can install fail2ban.
Finally i have found that running sshd on a non standard port helps with the automated scans too.